# LuaLaTeX: color the first word of each line

Tags: luatex

Let's say I have a document, and I want to colorize the first word of each line. That is to say, when a word is the first word of a line, it should be replaced by \textcolor{red}{[the word]}.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204055/macro-that-checks-for-the-beginning-of-a-line) had answered this in part, using discretionary ligatures, but this does not work when you begin a paragraph with a word, as well as the spacing problem.

I would think that a Lua(La)TeX solution is possible. Is there a way to go through each (typeset) line, get the first word of each (typeset) line and then replace that word with a colorized version using LuaTeX? That way, one doesn't have to manually color words, whether or not they occur at a spot for a discretionary ligature.

Comment: How should this work with hyphenation? Should the first full word be highlighted, everything until the first space or something else?

Comment: also what do you want to do if the line starts with punctuation like `(a phrase in parens)`  make `(` red or `a` red or `(a` red?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question doesn't really give enough details to determine the correct behavior in many cases, so this is a rather simple approach:

Only consider lines which go through the line breaking routines (So horizontal boxes are ignored) and then color all glyphs until a glue node is found. In most cases this seems to do "the right thing":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext,luacolor}
\newattribute\ColFirstAttr
\directlua{
  local ourattr = \number\allocationnumber;
  local glyph_id = node.id'glyph'
  local glue_id = node.id'glue'
  require'pre_append_to_vlist_filter'
  local luacolorattr = oberdiek.luacolor.getattribute()
  luatexbase.add_to_callback('pre_append_to_vlist_filter', function(head, kind)
    if not kind == 'post_linebreak' then return true end
    local attr = node.has_attribute(head, ourattr)
    if not attr then return true end
    local wordfound
    for n, id in node.traverse(head.head) do
      if id == glyph_id then
        node.set_attribute(n, luacolorattr, attr)
        wordfound = true
      elseif id == glue_id and wordfound then
        break
      end
    end
    return true
  end, 'color first word')
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\SetFirstColor{}
\protected\def\SetFirstColor#1#{%
  \@SetFirstColor{#1}%
}
\def\@SetFirstColor#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \color#1{#2}%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\ColFirstAttr\the\LuaCol@Attribute\space
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\SetFirstColor{red}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 even though that's a very funny shade of red:-)

Comment: There appears to be some code missing, including `\documentclass`

Comment: @JPi I added the missing line. (Except for the `\documentclass` everything was there.)

Comment: @MarcelKrüger: I would like `linenumber` for each line instead of color. How to achieve this. I have tried and not get the results. `lineno` package is having some problems in `figure and table floats`. So i would like to achieve in `LuaLaTeX`.