# Linenumbers include title, author using lualatex

Tags: luatex, lineno, directlua, lualatex-dev

I have got proper linenumbers in the twocolumn mode, except `title` and `authornames` . I have using `LuaLaTeX Version 1.17.1`. How to get auto linenumbers include all the texts(like title, author etc...). Any `lua` script is also welcome...

I have found [LuaLaTeX: color the first word of each line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539255/lualatex-color-the-first-word-of-each-line) beginning of each-word is color. It'll work linenumber instead of color? It's possible in Lua. I'm Beginner of Lua...

My Mwe IS:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,twocolumn]{ieeetran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}
\title{Cylindrical systems in general relativity}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{{Shini} {Dwiedi}, \textit{Student Member}\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}Department of Electrical Engineering, India}}

\IEEEtitleabstractindextext{
\begin{abstract}
Applications like teleconferencing, surveillance, and robot audition, yet the complexity introduced by sources impedes precise source localization. This article uses tracking approach in the spherical harmonics (SHs) domain.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
Direction of arrival, source tracking, spherical harmonic domain.
\end{keywords}}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```